# How to use pyparsing to parse mutiple lins Chinese text?

Tags: python, text, pattern-matching, extract, pyparsing

I want to use pyparsing to extract some block of string from a Chinese dataset. But `pyparsing.Word` is use for English, but work well in Chinese text, I tried to use Regex instead.

Due to stackoverflow can not post large Chinese text, I have to use pastebin,
here is the example data, and what I want to extract: https://pastebin.com/CrH2UBXH

As you see, I want to extract `1、... 2、 ....`(may be other Number Sequence like `(1) (2)` or `(一) (二)` ) between Chinese number `一、 二、 ...` .

#### My code:

```
from pyparsing import *

CN_TEXT = Regex('[\u4E00-\u9FA5A]*')
CN_NUM = Regex('[一二三四五六七八九十]')
bider = Regex('投标|投标人|投标单位|供应商')
qa = Regex('资质|资格|条件')

# start pattern is 
# t1  三、 供应商资质要求：
# t2  三、投标人资格要求 
# t3  一、合格的投标人必须具备以下条件：
# t4  五、供应商应具备的条件及资格：
qaStart = LineStart() + CN_NUM + CN_TEXT + bider + CN_TEXT + qa + CN_TEXT + Optional(':') + LineEnd()


# lines pattern
qaLineEmpty = Suppress(LineStart() + LineEnd())
qaLine = LineStart() + restOfLine() + LineEnd()
qaLines = OneOrMore(Optional(qaLine, qaLineEmpty )) # this is what I need

# another block start, it is this block end
qaEnd = LineStart() + CN_NUM

qaBlock = qaStart + qaLines + qaEnd

for i in [t1, t2, t3, t4]:
    print(qaBlock.parseString(i))
```

My code has error :

---

```
ParseException                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-61242b74d440> in <module>()
----> 1 qaStart.parseString(t1)

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyparsing.py in parseString(self, instring, parseAll)
   1615             else:
   1616                 # catch and re-raise exception from here, clears out pyparsing internal stack trace
-> 1617                 raise exc
   1618         else:
   1619             return tokens

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyparsing.py in parseString(self, instring, parseAll)
   1605             instring = instring.expandtabs()
   1606         try:
-> 1607             loc, tokens = self._parse( instring, 0 )
   1608             if parseAll:
   1609                 loc = self.preParse( instring, loc )

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyparsing.py in _parseNoCache(self, instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)
   1377             if self.mayIndexError or loc >= len(instring):
   1378                 try:
-> 1379                     loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
   1380                 except IndexError:
   1381                     raise ParseException( instring, len(instring), self.errmsg, self )

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyparsing.py in parseImpl(self, instring, loc, doActions)
   3374                     raise ParseSyntaxException(instring, len(instring), self.errmsg, self)
   3375             else:
-> 3376                 loc, exprtokens = e._parse( instring, loc, doActions )
   3377             if exprtokens or exprtokens.haskeys():
   3378                 resultlist += exprtokens

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyparsing.py in _parseNoCache(self, instring, loc, doActions, callPreParse)
   1381                     raise ParseException( instring, len(instring), self.errmsg, self )
   1382             else:
-> 1383                 loc,tokens = self.parseImpl( instring, preloc, doActions )
   1384 
   1385         tokens = self.postParse( instring, loc, tokens )

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyparsing.py in parseImpl(self, instring, loc, doActions)
   2773         result = self.re.match(instring,loc)
   2774         if not result:
-> 2775             raise ParseException(instring, loc, self.errmsg, self)
   2776 
   2777         loc = result.end()

ParseException: Expected Re:('投标|投标人|投标单位|供应商') (at char 2), (line:2, col:2)
```

Looks like I can not define regex rule like this, but what is the proper way?

Comment: Your parser spans multiple lines but you are only parsing one at a time. Try: `qaBlock.parseString('\n'.join([t1, t2, t3, t4]))`